# Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value using CoreLocation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm really new to swift and am trying to figure out why I am getting a nil value when running this program. I have tried adding a `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]!)` but that didn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Here is the code (PS: This is the value of the variable locManager: `var locManager = CLLocationManager()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        
        locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]!) {
            let locationZoom = locations.last as! CLLocation
            
        }
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() ==  .authorizedAlways
        {
            currentLocation = locManager.location
            //getting locations
            let longa = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude ***<- (Error occurring at this line)*** 
            let latta = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
            nearbyLocations1(latitude: latta, longitude: longa) { (longitude, latitude, name, vicinity) in
                       
                    print("name 1 is ", name)
                   }
            nearbyLocations2(latitude: latta, longitude: longa) { (longitude, latitude, name, vicinity) in
                print("name 2 is ", name)
            }
            
        } 
        
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably currentLocation = nil. Use

```
if let currentLocation = locManager.location {
    // Code for currentLocation != nil
} else {
    // Code for currentLocation == nil
}
```

or something similar.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. The program is not showing an error, but the code is not being executed

Answer (score 1):

There are two major issues:

1. The method `didUpdateLocations` must be declared on the top level of the class (same level as `viewDidLoad`) and all the code to process the location must be inside this method

   ```
   func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]!) {
        guard let currentLocation = locations.last else { return }
        //getting locations
        let longa = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude 
        let latta = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
        nearbyLocations1(latitude: latta, longitude: longa) { (longitude, latitude, name, vicinity) in                       
            print("name 1 is ", name)
        }
        nearbyLocations2(latitude: latta, longitude: longa) { (longitude, latitude, name, vicinity) in
            print("name 2 is ", name)
        }
   }
   ```

2. To get the locations you have to set the delegate of the location manager to `self` and call `startUpdatingLocation()`